# color in button background with css

Tags: html, css

I'm building my navigation bar and I currently am using 3 images for each option on the menu.
I'm using css to replace the images based on when its non-selected, hovered, and selected.
Using html and css, i only knew how to highlight the actual words (ie home, order, how it works...), i couldn't figure out a way to color in the whole box when selected.

Is there a way to do this with html/css without using image files?

[image]

Comment: and background-color isn't what your after?? Based on your image screen shot you should be able to do it with css (with properties background-color, color etc) around the states of :hover, :active, :link and possibly adding classes to ones you need to style differently. Hard to say completely without some code, and exactly what images you are using

Comment: That's just `color:white` and `background:red`.

Answer (score 1):

So little information provided but still I will try assuming the most general way.

In a basic `ul` and `li` menu structure, like the following.

```
<ul>

    <li>

        <a href="#">Link Text</a>

    </li>

</ul>
```

The box surrounding all the menus are selected by simply

```
ul {
    /* Styles */
}
```

The box surrounding a menu item (***probably what you are asking***) is selected by `ul > li`

```
ul > li {   
    /* Style */
    background-color: red;
}
```

*Note: You can also use `ul li { ... }` for more general way.*

Where as, link itself is selected by `ul > li a`

```
ul > li a {
    /* Style */
}
```

Try to implement this on your case.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to achieve this effect using a combination of `color` and `background-color`.

Answer (score 1):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/DHVk1sE9)***

...........................
Hi now do this easily as like this

**css**

```
    ul{
list-style:none;
  width:200px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background:green;
}
ul li{
display:block;
  background:pink;
  margin:3px;
}
a:hover{
background:red;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  padding:0 30px;
  line-height:35px;
  position:relative;
}
.shope{
padding-left:60px;
}
.shope:hover{
background:none;
}
.shope:after{
content:'';
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:8px;
  width:30px;
  height:20px;
  background:lightgreen;
}
.shope:before{
content:'';
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:8px;
  width:30px;
  height:20px;
  background:darkred;
}
```

**html**

```
    <ul>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="shope">my cart 1</a></li>

</ul>
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/DHVk1sE9)***

Answer (score 1):

to have different colors of menus on hover

have your css something like this:

```
div.home:hover{
color: #4C787E;
}
div.aboutus:hover{
color: #616D7E;
}
div.contact:hover{
color: #808000;
}
```

and html goes like this:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li class="menu1"><div class="home"><a href="#">home</a></div>
</li>
<li class="menu2"><div class="aboutus"><a href="...">about us</a></div></li>
<li class="menu3"><div class="contact"><a href="...">contact</a></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

same as above you can apply it on the sub-menus also.

Try it.

Hope it helps you.